# Operation of this power amplifier

Tags: audio

My query is that..At node B the voltage is 11.7 V ..and at node A it is 11V according to text, but it should be two diode drop below the voltage at node B i.e it should be 10.3 V(because 0.7V voltage is getting dropped at BE junction of Q1 and across D1) please explain why i am having a contradictory idea ???

[image]

Comment: In signal analysis we assume there is no direct connection between Opamp output and and the input side,a equivalent Opamp figure is given in the link see.[here](http://www.analog-electronics.eu/analog-electronics/modified-nodal-analysis/OpAmpFollower-SimpleModel.png).[for more](http://www.analog-electronics.eu/analog-electronics/modified-nodal-analysis/modified-nodal-analysis.xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

D1 is forwarded biased by R4 so the voltage is 0.7V above the voltage at A. You have to pay attention to the signs. The NPN transistor emitter is about 0.7V lower, so almost equal to the voltage at A.

The same is true of the PNP transistor, with signs reversed, so the outout is at about the same voltage as A.

Comment: Q1(npn)transistor emitter is at 11V due to 0.7 V drop at base emitter junction...but why at node A it is 11v ..it should be 10.3 V because of another voltage drop of 0.7 V across diode D1..????

Comment: The diode *adds* to the voltage at A and Q1 Vbe *subtracts* so you're left with almost the same voltages at A and output.

Comment: exactly how ???

Comment: Assume A is fixed. Follow the signs just as you drew them. -+ adds, +- subtracts. Is that what you mean? Or are you asking why the junctions are forward biased?

Comment: no... i got it ..actually if we see the diodes from R4 onwards they are in parallel...and in parrallel the volatge is same...if the diode were to be in series then the voltages subracts two two diode drops and my earlier assumption would be right then...as simple as that...

Comment: but one thing i dont understand is...why R6(Q1 emitter resistor) is not included in this parrallel combination....since same current flowing across Q1 base emitter junction also flows through R6....

Comment: There is not much current flowing through R6 when there is no load current. Maybe a few mA (the bias current of the push-pull output stage), so the voltage drop is almost zero (perhaps 100-200mV). To get to that level of accuracy you have to apply a more sophisticated model of junction voltage- Ebers-Moll etc. or run a SPICE simulation. See, for example, the equations for a Widlar current source, which is the same configuration.

Comment: means for practical purposes voltage across R6 can be neglected??

Comment: Also the text says that the resistor R4 and R5 provide an active pullup for transistor Q1 and Q2...what do they mean by "active pullup"

Comment: Don't know- looks pretty passive to me.

Comment: One more problem I encountered is that  the voltage drop across R4 and R5 should be minimum in order to produce the base current.But this minimum voltage requirement keeps the amplifier maximum peak output voltage well below the supply voltage level and thus limits the amplifier efficiency...exactly how???

Comment: Calculate efficiency and you'll see- higher supply compared to output voltage is less efficient.

Comment: what i know is that if VR4 and VR5 is minimum it will produce large base current which is one of the requirement to drive the transistors in(or near) saturation ...but this is against what text says in my previous post....please justify in terms of voltages or current..